# GCE RAM and CPU usage in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-stackdriver

Is there a way to export Google Compute Engine instances logs into BigQuery which will allow you to query the exported logs to get CPU and RAM usage for a selected period using the instance label?

I reviewed already the [Default Logging Agent logs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/default-logs#custom_types) doc which shows what Stackdriver Logging collects but RAM and CPU usage isn't mentioned.

I also found this [Viewing Activity Logs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/activity-logs) and [Exporting with the Logs Viewer](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/configure_export_v2) but none of them are relevant to my need.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Stackdriver has some specific GCP metrics - no need for custom types (those on the "default logging aggent logs" linked in the question):

- https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-compute

They include `instance/cpu/utilization` and other cpu metrics. I'm not sure why memory is not listed, as it's part of many other services (in the same page) default reporting.

Comment: I'm afraid that the link you shared doesn't help me as I'm looking to export logs of CPU usage and RAM from GCE instance to BQ

Comment: I'll do some further exploration - thanks for noting that

Comment: For those of you who are interested, I've file an Issue Tracker here: https://issuetracker.google.com/112425538