# How to know the CPU/RAM resource used in GCP BigQuery on every successful query and the cost details

Tags: google-bigquery

Though the same question has been asked before here but no accepted answer is seen:
[GCE RAM and CPU usage in BigQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51773144/gce-ram-and-cpu-usage-in-bigquery)

The question is simple, for every successful query executed in BigQuery, how do I know how much computing resource was consumed? how many CPU cores, RAM were used? And how the query was charged?

An example below is from a Job execution on GCP:

[image]

Thank you.

**[Update]**

Some SOers suggested `dry-run`, I tried

```
bq query "SELECT COUNT(1) as rowcount, COUNTIF(corpus = 'hamlet') as rowcount_hamlet FROM publicdata.samples.shakespeare order by rowcount_hamlet desc" --dry-run=true 

bq query "SELECT COUNT(1) as rowcount, COUNTIF(corpus = 'hamlet') as rowcount_hamlet FROM publicdata.samples.shakespeare order by rowcount_hamlet desc" dry-run=true
```

Both are not working for me. Can anyone advise the right format please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like a screenshot of Cloud Dataflow metrics, not BigQuery. BigQuery is a fully-managed service. That means all the infrastructure running your queries is pretty much abstracted away from you. What you can analysis however, is the number of `slots` used per query and the [query execution plan](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-plan-explanation) to get an idea of what kind os resources are being consumed to run your queries. You need to drill in on the `[slot][2]` metric. From memory, a slot is roughly half of a CPU core and about 1 GB of RAM.

Comment: Thank you, the Execution details seems only available AFTER the query is executed already, correct me if I am wrong. I know I can check the plan in advance in Cloudera Hive/Impala, does BigQuery provide that somewhere in advance as well? Can you post a screenshot if yes? Beside, If I execute a query in BigQuery, may I assume there is actually a job in the back-end? if yes, where can I see the job's id? I am asking because I might need to retrieve query plan info by the job id as per this doc: `https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/get`, thank you Graham.

Comment: _"for every successful query executed in BigQuery"_ - I thought you needed the stats for the queries you've already executed? If you want to check what the query cost would be but without running it, you can use `dry-run=true`. But, I'm not aware of anything that gives you more info on the query before running it (I could be wrong).

Comment: Thank you Graham, I just tried to set dry-run=true, both `253  bq query "SELECT COUNT(1) as rowcount, COUNTIF(corpus = 'hamlet') as rowcount_hamlet FROM publicdata.samples.shakespeare order by rowcount_hamlet desc" --dry-run=true` and `254  bq query "SELECT COUNT(1) as rowcount, COUNTIF(corpus = 'hamlet') as rowcount_hamlet FROM publicdata.samples.shakespeare order by rowcount_hamlet desc" dry-run=true` are not working for me. Can you advise the right format please? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To [price your queries before running them](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-costs#price_your_queries_before_running_them) you must use the `--dry_run` flag in the CLI and the `dryRun` parameter in the job configuration when you use the API or client libraries, then use the [Google Cloud Platform Pricing Calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator/) to estimate the cost.

Here is an example query from the documentation:

```
bq query \
--use_legacy_sql=false \
--dry_run \
'SELECT
   COUNTRY,
   AIRPORT,
   IATA
 FROM
   `project_id`.dataset.airports
 LIMIT
   1000'
```

I suggest you to read through the [BigQuery best practices](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-costs) to control costs.

Comment: Thank you for the Calculator, that is very nice, however, forgive my silly question here: for Big Query, seems everyone can use it without even creating a project if it is just for practicing on the public dataset, meaning it is free in that case?

Comment: Yes, the pricing calculator is free and you don't need to create a project to use it. When querying on the [public dataset](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/public-data/), the first 1TB per month is free, subject to [query pricing details](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#queries).

Comment: You are welcome. Please remind to accept the answer if it solved your question so it can help the community in future cases.

Comment: Thanks for the reminding, I am waiting to see if anyone can share a working query with dry-run, I mentioned that in a comment to Graham, should have udpated it in the OP.

Comment: It is `--dry_run` with an underscore. And you just need to add the flag, don't set it to True or False. I will edit my answer to add the example query provided in the documentation.

Comment: Thank you very much, can you please add your correction to your answer? btw, dry_run shows only how much data, no others like CPU/RAM?

Comment: No, it doesn't show CPU/RAM. To get an idea of that, refer to the answer from @Graham.